# timemachine doesn't start or send errors

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, catalina

Time Machine is stuck here in this screen i erased my drive to be formatted as journaled and it looks like this now but time machine doesn't respond after configuration[image: here is the backup drive after format]

[image: I just got the option to use drive as a backup and i chose yes even when i select backup disk nothing happens]

this is what i do but nothing happen 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time machine doesn’t want to back up part of one disk to another disk, but your screen shot seems to show that. To be sure, I would confirm you are not just splitting up one drive and have two devices to set this up.

**It might be possible to convince Time Machine from the command line to backup, so if you’re up for that, here are the two commands I would use to get you started:**

```
diskutil list
```

And then

```
tmutil destinationinfo
```

Based on your specific naming, you might be able to add your drive - being careful with characters like ( and ) - I would probably make your backup volume just “backup” without any punctuation like the smart quotes to the left

```
tmutil setdestination /volumes/backupdrivename
```

this will tell you where the error exists and try to search for it. 
maybe a permission error. remember you maybe have to try the same command with 'sudo'

if the config is done but it won't start try to start the backup from command also

```
tmutil startbackup && tmutil status
```

you will notice that backup started at timemachine app

Comment: I will try this but can you explain more what do you mean by first 2 paragraph es and what exactly these commands do

Comment: I’ll let you search them a bit or type “man diskutil” or “man tmutil” to read the manual pages. When you run them alone, they also have short helps. @amr

Comment: yes okay thanks that gives me another way to solve the problem but is there a problem that the backup external drive is a child like in the picture that i attached

Comment: Yes - you might need to wipe that external or let TIme Machine format it for you. Having multiple partitions isn’t the main way I test or set this up. I would presume Apple might not test your situation - it could work, but I don’t know

Comment: i could say that this is the answer i was looking for because it allowed me to trace the error by   'tmutil setdestination 'drive directory' ' command........ for me it was an permissions problem so i solve it but anyone can do this and search for the command error that will prompt

Comment: Well done @amr . If you want to post an answer or edit mine with your command and error, that’s great. I do love the errors I get from `tmutil` and all the extra detail it can provide.